# Arch linux not booting after replacement of mother board

Tags: arch-linux, boot, bios

I have been using arch for a few months. but due to a mother board issue, I had to get it replaced. Since then, the os doesn't boot. Dell Support Assist says No bootable device found, with a QR code when scanned takes me to dell website and says the error code is 0000 and the validation code is 91042.

in Bios, Boot sequence is empty, secure boot is switched off, and SATA operatioon is set to AHCI mode.

When I try to add a Boot option in the Boot list option, I get popup to select a file with this directory tree...

```
Grub
| x86_64-efi
| | acpi.mod
| | adler32.mod
| | affs.mod
| | ... and a lot more .mod files
| locale
| | ca.mo
| | da.mo
| | de.mo
| | ... and a lot more .mo files
| themes
| | COPYING.CC-BY-SA-3.0
| | README
| | blob_w.png
| | boot_menu_c.png
| | boot_menu_e.png
| | ... and a lot more .png files
| | theme.txt
| | ... there are a few .pf2 files like
| | dejavu_10.pf2
| | dejavu_12.pf2 ...
| fonts
| | unicode.pf2
| grub.cfg
| grubenv
EFI
| arch
| | grubx64.efi
| Dell
| | logs
| | | diags_previous.xml
| | | diags_current.xml
vmlinuz-linux
initramf-linux.img
initramfs-linux-fallback.imp
inter-ucode.img
```

In this EFI Boot Selection menu, it says file system is FS0

Comment: This doesn't sound like a software issue. It certainly isn't an Arch issue since you're failing before the OS is even loaded. So I'm afraid we won't be able to help much. My first guess would be that your hard disk is either not connected, or not correctly connected or even that the motherboard has an issue. Can you see the hard drive(s) in the BIOS?

Comment: If the boot sequence in the firmware setup is empty, but you are prompted to select a file, try selecting grubx64.efi from the list. Your problem is that the UEFI boot variables where this was set went with the old motherboard, and the new motherboard came with an empty list.

Comment: @terdon, yes I can see the SSD in the BIOS, it is listed.  and this is a brand new motherboard, I just collected the laptop from the service center and they say ever test has been done and it is perfectly fine, so I hardly doubt it is a mother board issue.

Comment: @JohanMyréen, I'll try that out.

Comment: @JohanMyréen, thanks man. It worked. I can now boot into arch. 
But it took me two months to fix this motherboard issue. So now I don't remember my password. I should figure that out now.

Comment: Nice catch, @JohanMyréen! Please post an answer with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The UEFI firmware defines variables which control, among other things, the boot sequence. The boot variables contain paths to EFI programs that are tried, one at a time, until one is successfully loaded (or the list is exhausted).

These UEFI variables are stored in non-volatile memory on the motherboard. Since the motherboard was replaced, the old variables were lost and the new board was shipped with an empty boot sequence.

The firmware on the new motherboard kindly prompts you to select a file, so try selecting grubx64.efi from the list to choose the GRUB bootloader as the EFI program to run.